# change Binding List item based on the DataGridView's row index

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I have binded a `BindingList` to a `DataGridView`. What I'm trying to do now is changing the underlying item of the BindingList represented in a DataGridView row.

So what I'm trying to achieve is to find a list item of the `BindingList` by the corresponding DataGridView row index in order to change that specific item in the `BindingList` and ultimately the corresponding `DataGridView` row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem(v=vs.110).aspx) to get reference to the source object bound to a specific `DataGridViewRow`. Since you have binded the `BindingList` to the `DataGridView`, the object returned will originate from that list. Something like this

```
DataGridViewRow row = ...;
var sourceObject = (YourObjectType)row.DataBoundItem;
// do something with the object
```

Another way is to use [DataGridViewRow.Index Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.index(v=vs.110).aspx) in combination with your binding list like this:

```
DataGridViewRow row = ...;
var sourceObject = yourBindingList[row.Index];
// do something with the object
```

Comment: Exactly I want the reverse. Find row from the bound item

Comment: @F.I.V No predefined method AFAIK. Write your own using `for` / `foreach` loop or LINQ like `dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => Equals(r.DataBoundItem, boundItem))`